# Can you iteratively add only certain components to a JPanel from the fields of a class?

Tags: java, swing, reflection, field

I want to add all the components of one type to a JPanel using a loop. This is my first thought:

```
public class UI extends JFrame{
    private JLabel aLbl;
    private JLabel bLbl;
    private Component someOtherComponentA;
    private Component someOtherComponentB;
    private JPanel panel;

    public UI(){
       panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       //this is what I am trying to do
       for(JLabel l : Just_the_JLabels)
           panel.add(l);
    }     
}
```

I was thinking I could use reflection to obtain all the fields of the JLabel type, but then I couldn't figure out how to obtain the instance of the object assigned to the field. I have a long list of components and thought that it would look nicer in the code and be less tedious if I didn't copy paste panel.add(aLbl), panel.add(bLbl), panel.add(cLbl), etc.

Instead I was going to do something like this:

```
for(Field f : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
    if(f.getType() == JLabel.class)
        //what goes in place of "object associated with field f"
        panel.add(object associated with the field f)
}
```

---edit---

Solution:
    public class UI extends JFrame{
        private ArrayList = new ArrayList();

```
    public UI(){
        init();
    }

    public void setLbl(JLabel l){
        list.add(l)
    }

    private init(){
        setLabel(new JLabel("labelName"); //do this for each label

        for(JLabel label : list)
            panel.add(label);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create the getter & setter in your `UI` class for `JLabel` an now you can get the object using `Method#invoke()` on getter methods.

---

I don't know why are you using `reflection`?

There are lots of other ways. Try to avoid `reflection` at all.

```
for (Field f : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (f.getType() == JLabel.class) {
        // adjust the method name as per the getter/setter methods name
        Method method = this.getClass().getMethod("get" + f.getName());
        System.out.println(method.getName());
        Object object = method.invoke(this);
        if (object != null) {
            System.out.println(object.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

---

--EDIT--

Try in the way without using `reflection`

```
private List<JLabel> list = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

// set the label using setter method 
// same for others also
public void setaLbl(JLabel aLbl) {
    if (aLbl != null) {
        // add in the list 
        list.add(aLbl);
    }
    this.aLbl = aLbl;
}

// now simply iterate the list

for(JLabel l : list){
    panel.add(l);
}
```

Comment: Without using reflection, how would you iterate over the the JLabel fields? If I can avoid using reflection I will.

Comment: create an array of `JLabel`.

Comment: If I created an array of JLabel, I would have to add all the labels to the array manually. I might as well have just added the labels to the JPanel manually, right?

Comment: Please can you tell me how you are creating the labels?

Comment: **`reflection` slow down the applicaion.**

Comment: oops, they are like this in another initialization method.
    JLabel aLbl = new JLabel("this is a label")
I have many of them.

Comment: call in this way `setaLbl(new JLabel("this is a label"))` to add in the list also, if possible.

Comment: Right now there are 28, but there could be more. this.aLbl = aLbl will just reassign the field aLbl with each call. I think making all the labels anonymous might help. I won't have to deal with the fields at all and I can just iterate over a list of anonymous labels.

Comment: Now you have two options. Choose any one which is relevant to your code.

Comment: Your suggestion to use setter method that added the label to a list helped me, but I removed the `this.aLbl = aLbl` as it did nothing for me.